# JDBC significantly faster than OCCI. Should I be surprised?

Tags: java, c++, oracle, jdbc

I'm very surprised by a performance test comparing OCCI (Oracle C++ Call Interface) and the old JDBC.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <occi.h>

using namespace oracle::occi;
using namespace std;

const string username   = "system";
const string password   = "******";
const string url        = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)))";
const string sql        = "select * from CREDITO.movtos_cuentas";

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cout << "Oracle Connectivity" << endl;

    Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);
    Connection *conn = env->createConnection(username, password, url);
    Statement *stm = conn->createStatement(sql);
    ResultSet *rs = stm->executeQuery();

    unsigned long count = 0;

    while (rs->next()) {
        count++;
    }

    stm->closeResultSet(rs);
    conn->terminateStatement(stm);
    env->terminateConnection(conn);
    Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);

    cout << "Registros na CREDITO.MOVTOS_CUENTAS: " << count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And here is Java code:

```java
package oraconnect.jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class OraconnectJdbc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stm = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe", "system", "******");
            stm = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stm.executeQuery("select * from CREDITO.movtos_cuentas");
            long count = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                count++;
            }

            System.out.printf("Registros na CREDITO.MOVTOS_CUENTAS: %d\n", count);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    //Ignore
                }
            }
            if (stm != null) {
                try {
                    stm.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    //Ignore
                }
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    //Ignore
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Execution:

C++ Version

```
time LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/eduardo/Private/Oracle/instantclient_11_2/. ./oraconnect
```

Java Version

```
time java -jar oraconnect-jdbc.jar -cp lib/oracle-driver-11.2.0.3.jar
```

C++ Result:

```
real    1m29.392s
user    0m32.788s
sys     0m20.812s
```

Java Result:

```
real    0m28.404s
user    0m12.076s
sys     0m4.236s
```

Conclusion:

Java was significantly faster than C++

I wonder if I have made a mistake or used some bad practice with the C++ version. Can anybody help me to understand this result?

Comment: He posts a question and you cannot believe what happens next!

Comment: NathanOliver, results posted.

Comment: Conclusion - the one you ran second is faster because a bunch of data had already been pulled from disk and was sitting in SGA.

Comment: Why do you say the "old JDBC"? Oracle constantly improves its JDBC drivers by adding new features and performance optimizations.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance to improve the question, but I would like you to focus on finding a solution to the question, which is the most important. I understand that this is enough to understand and try to respond. We will all win with the solution on the problem.

Comment: @GaryMyers You're saying that if the poster had the run the Java code first, the result would've been reversed?

Answer (score 2):

As you measured the time, the differences are valid. 
If you want to understand, why they are different, you need to split up the whole time into some parts and see if they are similar or different . and understand the reason for the difference. 
This can be done by many different methods, like tracing or sampling the call stacks on your binaries, doing a tcpdump on network layer or many others. 
A very handy method is enabling SQL_TRACE in the Oracle database - there you get a lot of information where time is spent. A good introduction about methods to enable SQL_TRACE is https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof.
These tracefiles contain a lot of data and are hard to be read, especially at the beginning. Several tools, (most are called "Profiler") are available to process these files. The leading product (from my perspective) is *Method-R Profiler* - but as this costs money you might to try https://antognini.ch/2017/03/tvdxtat-4-0-beta-11/ instead.

Without any further information, no one can tell what's the reason for performance differences. But with the tools available you can identify them. then you either accept one solution faster than the other, or fix it.

**Edit:**
I will provide an example:
Beside many other reasons, there is a difference in the default behavior: 
OCCI fetches 2 rows at a time: 
[Accessing Oracle Database Using C++](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNCPP/accessing-oracle-database-using-cplusplus.htm#LNCPP0036)

> By default, prefetching is turned on and the database fetches an extra
>   row all the time.

But jdbc has a result set of 10:
[Database JDBC Developer's Guide - Result Set](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#JJDBC28621)

> By default, when Oracle JDBC runs a query, it retrieves a result set
>   of 10 rows at a time from the database cursor.

So it can happen you have 5 times more network roundtrips with OCCI than with jdbc.

This is only an example - it might be the reason for your observation or not. To be sure, you need to measure, not guess or ask for guesswork.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I agree that for a good understand your suggestion is good. But it is a very simple test with one connection to local database and a simple SELECT in a table. I was very surprises that Java is 3 times faster than C++ with OCCI (Oracle solution for C++). For me it is a surprisilly results.

Comment: I question whether Oracle's solution (OCCI) is a good solution.

Comment: Hi Martin, actually when I equalized fetch size, the difference was approximate, but JDBC was still superior to OCCI. OCCI = 19s and JDBC = 12s.